# php, why we shouldn't use get('var');

Tags: php, variables

I'm just wondering, if there is anything else (like security issues etc) other than our code clarity why we should avoid getting class variable by this code

```
    getVar('var');
```

instead of:

```
   getId(); getName(); etc. etc.
```

?

Comment: What are you talking about ?

Comment: Well, if your getters/setters actually need to do anything else where would you put the code?  There is a time and place for magic methods.

Comment: as @hsz says, you have to provide more information, what libraries are you using that provides `getVar`?  if it is a class perhaps the biggest reason to use getters is to support encapsulation

Comment: Would you happen to be talking about Joomla!, specifically [`JRequest::getVar()`](http://docs.joomla.org/Retrieving_and_Filtering_GET_and_POST_requests_with_JRequest::getVar)?

Comment: if it is joomla it is a functio provided by their request library with the specific purpose of `Unless other parameters are set, all HTML and trailing whitespace will be filtered out.`

Answer (score 3):

I guess one reason would be so that your IDE can help you by auto-completing and type-hinting the method names.

If you're using a generic get method as per your first example, the IDE won't be able to give you any of that help.

Also, if it's a public API (ie developers other than yourself are going to use it), it would really help them to have a fixed interface to work with, rather than an single get method that doesn't tell them what the possible options are for it.

Since we're talking specifically about PHP here, it's worth pointing out that the functionality you're describing is very similar to PHP's built-in `__get()` method. This method works much the way you've described `getVar()`, but exposes the variables as properties.

This also has similar issues with IDE type hinting, but that can be worked around if you're using decent IDE, by using documentation comments to tell the IDE what properties are supported. A `getVar()` method wouldn't have this option.

Comment: So far 3 Votes for a good answer and 10 useful so far for a 'what?' comment?  Kudos for your reading comprehension and good answer!